# How can iterate through arrays of two different sizes and perform different operations on each one in python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to implement the Gillespie algorithm in python 3.7. 
I have two arrays:

```
popul_num = np.array([100, 200, 0, 0])
```

and

```
LHS = np.array([[1,1,0,0], [0,0,1,0], [0,0,1,0]])
```

In the first array each element represents the discrete number of molecules for each reactant in the system and in the second array each row represents a reaction, where each element of the row represents the stochiometric coefficient of the reactant.

I need to loop through both arrays and calculate the binomial coefficient using the number of discrete molecules from the first array and the corresponding stochiometries of the reactants in each reaction of the second array. Each row of the LHS array should be positionally dependent on the popul_num array.

I havent got very far

```
for i in LHS[0:3]:       
for j in popul_num:     
        aj = binom(j, i)        
        print(aj)
```

but the output for this is:

```
[100. 100.   1.   1.]
[200. 200.   1.   1.]
[0. 0. 1. 1.]
[0. 0. 1. 1.]
[  1.   1. 100.   1.]
[  1.   1. 200.   1.]
[1. 1. 0. 1.]
[1. 1. 0. 1.]
[  1.   1. 100.   1.]
[  1.   1. 200.   1.]
[1. 1. 0. 1.]
[1. 1. 0. 1.]
```

which uses every element of each row in LHS with all the elements of popul_num. I want to just use each element of each row in LHS on the possitionally corresponding element in popul_num once.

any ideas

sorry for the long post
cheers

Comment: Can you share an example of the corresponding elements in each array?

Comment: The elements in both arrays represent the following entities; Enzyme; Substrate; Enzyme-substrate complex and products. LHS represents three different reactions (one reaction in each row) using the the four entities, the elements in popul_num represent the discrete number of each entity. The 1st position in both arrays corresponds to the substrate and the other positions are respective of the order i gave in the top of the comment. cheers

Comment: That kind of information should go in the post itself, comments are brittle and difficult to read.

Comment: sorry! Do you have any suggestions ? : )